# How to setup an ingress controller for kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Sorry I am new with Kubernetes and everything...
I have a java back-end in a clusterIP service and a front-end in a NodePort service. I try to make a request to the backend from the front (from the navigator) and it doesn't work.

I saw that I needed to setup an ingress crontroller in order to make it work, but each time I do a "minikube tunnel" and go to my localhost, I get a NGINX 404 error. And the address http://toto.virtualisation doesn't work too (like it doesn't exist).

Here is the setup of my front and my ingress controller in my yaml file :

```
# Front Deployment 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: front-end-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: front-end
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: front-end
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: front-end-container
          image: oxasa/front-end-image:latest
---
# Front Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: front-end-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      targetPort: 80
      port: 80
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: front-end
--- 
# Front Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: front-end-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: toto.virtualisation
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: front-end-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

If you see anything that needs to be done to make it work...

Comment: Have you enabled the NGINX ingress controller that ships with minikube `minikube addons enable ingress`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

To the Ingress resource to ensure nginx picks up the created ingress.

Also Ingress is not required for service to service Communication. You can use the Kubernetes internal DNS from your Frontend service.
You can make the Frontend access backend by using sth like {service-name}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local